# Getting 404 on get request for generated file .svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js when running local development server

Tags: sveltekit

I am learning Svelte-kit and I am working on an existing project. However, when I try to run the project in development mode, I encounter a problem.

The issue arises when I attempt to run my project locally with `vite dev`. When I try to access a site there is a GET request for the file `.svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js` that results in a 404 Not found error. The site renders, but seems to be frozen.

The issue seems to be that my application is trying to locate this file using an absolute path on my machine rather than the correct path, which is `localhost:5173/.svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js`. If I attempt to access the file directly via this URL, it works correctly.

However, when the GET request is made, it utilizes the path: `localhost:5173/@fs/home/<myuser>/<myprojectfolder>/.svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js`, which results in the following error:

```
Error: Not found: /@fs/home/<myuser>/<myprojectfolder>/.svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js
    at resolve (/home/<myuser>/<myprojectfolder>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:473:13)
    at resolve (/home/<myuser>/<myprojectfolder>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:282:5)
    at #options.hooks.handle (/home/<myuser>/<myprojectfolder>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:56:56)
    at Module.respond (/home/<myuser>/<myprojectfolder>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:279:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

However, when I build the application and run it with `vite preview`, it works perfectly fine.

Here's my svelte.config.js:

```js
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

export default {
    preprocess: [vitePreprocess()],
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        csrf: {
            checkOrigin: false,
        }
    }
};
```

My vite.config.js is as follows:

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
});
```

My dependencies in package.json:

```json
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.5.0",
        "svelte": "^3.54.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.2.3",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
        "chartjs-adapter-date-fns": "^3.0.0",
        "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
        "form-data": "^4.0.0",
        "formdata-node": "^5.0.0",
        "mongodb": "^5.1.0",
        "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
        "svelte-chartjs": "^3.1.2"
    }
```

I have tried deleting node_modules and generated code and reinstalled it, but it did not make a difference.

I would appreciate any suggestions on why this may be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found that the issue was related to having spaces in one of the folders in my project path, which after cloning the repository were encoded to `%20` (`my%20project%20with%20spaces`). After removing the `%20` from the folder name the development server started to work again.